# Accessing same indexed element within 2D array swift

Tags: arrays, swift

Is there a syntactical way in Swift to access the same indexed element within arrays within a 2D array, akin to accessing a column in a table, e.g.

```
let A = [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ], [ 7, 8, 9 ] ]

A[ 2 ]
```

yields [ 7, 8, 9 ]. Is there a way to do something like

```
A[][ 2 ]
```

yields [ 3, 6, 9 ]?

I know I can do:

```
var B = [ Int ]()
for c in A {
    B.append( c[ 2 ] )
}
```

But I was wondering if there was another, perhaps syntactical, way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
A.map { (elem) -> Int in
    return elem[2]
}
```

Or the short version (credits to @Ian):

```
A.map { $0[2] }
```

Comment: Or just `A.map { $0[2] }`

Comment: @ian true, I have added it to my answer.